# Crystal Reports 2016 Failed to open Document

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working in a SQL Server environment, using Crystal Reports 2016 to retrieve and display data.

I made some several updates to a specific report over the last few hours, saved and closed the report, and when I try to open it again I get the following error message:

*%1 could not be found 

Failed to open document*

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? I have no idea where to even begin here. It's not a memory issue on the machine or a database connection issue.

Comment: Could you give us the query or code resulting in this error?

Comment: Have you tried opening the report by double-clicking on the .RPT file in File Explorer?  Does this produce the same error?  Also, do you have any kind of backup that would allow you to restore the report to the last known working version of the report?